# jQuery Validation Submitting without Validation in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, validation

I've put together a pretty simple competition script - it's commented out below and you can find the demo at http://www.jakeisonline.com/stackoverflow/jqueryvalidation/page/

I am using a jquery plugin to achieve the validation: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

The problem is only in Firefox (3.5.2) - the form submits without any validation at all, and ignores the ajax. IE8 & 7 seem to be fine.

```
$("#f").validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: function() {
                    if ($.trim($("#first_name").val()) === 'e.g. Jane') {
                        $("#first_name").val('').removeClass('example');
                        return $("#first_name").val();
                    }                       
                }
            },
            email: {
                required: function() {
                    if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === 'jane@example.com') {
                        $("#email").val('').removeClass('example');
                        return $("#email").val();
                    }
                }
            },
            friend_1_name: {
                required: function() {
                    if ($.trim($("#friend_1_name").val()) === 'e.g. Jane') {
                        $("#friend_1_name").val('').removeClass('example');
                        return $("#friend_1_name").val();
                    }                       
                }
            },
            friend_1_email: {
                required: function() {
                    if ($.trim($("#friend_1_email").val()) === 'jane@example.com') {
                        $("#friend_1_email").val('').removeClass('example');
                        return $("#friend_1_email").val();
                    }
                }
            },
            friend_2_name: {
                required: "#friend_2_email:filled"
            },
            friend_2_email: {
                required: "#friend_2_name:filled"
            },
            friend_3_name: {
                required: "#friend_3_email:filled"
            },
            friend_3_email: {
                required: "#friend_3_name:filled"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");                  

            // See if they also opted-in to the main mailing list, if they did, set that interest and add them to the mailing list
            if ($('#optin').is(':checked')) {
                alert('hello');
                $.post("", { first_name: $("#first_name").val(), email: $("#email").val(), key: "sub-678-1.50;1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0;2.1;subscribe-50.htm", 'prefs[]': ["1", "2"] });
                // Display the opt-in confirmation message
                $("#thanks_subscribing").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#optintickbox").hide();

                // Fade out the confirmation
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#thanks_subscribing").fadeOut("slow")
                },10000);

            } else {
                // Add them to the Entries Mailing List
            $.post("", { first_name: $("#first_name").val(), email: $("#email").val(), key: "sub-678-1.50;1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0;2.1;subscribe-50.htm", followup: "1", prefs: "2"} );
            }

            // Now start going through their friends, the first friend will always be filled out, so we don't need to check that
            $.post("", { first_name: $("#friend_1_name").val(), email: $("#friend_1_email").val(), key: "sub-678-1.51;1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0;2.1;subscribe-51.htm", followup: "2", custom_4: $("#first_name").val(), custom_5: $("#email").val()} );

            if ($("#friend_2_email").val() !== '') {
                $.post("", { first_name: $("#friend_2_name").val(), email: $("#friend_2_email").val(), key: "sub-678-1.51;1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0;2.1;subscribe-51.htm", followup: "2", custom_4: $("#first_name").val(), custom_5: $("#email").val()} );
            }

            if ($("#friend_3_email").val() !== '') {
                $.post("", { first_name: $("#friend_3_name").val(), email: $("#friend_2_email").val(), key: "sub-678-1.51;1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0;2.1;subscribe-51.htm", followup: "2", custom_4: $("#first_name").val(), custom_5: $("#email").val()} );
            }

            // Remove all of the submitted data to stop button spamming
            $("#friend_1_name, #friend_1_email, #friend_2_name, #friend_2_email, #friend_3_name, #friend_3_email").val('');

            // Bring the submit button out of disabled state
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");

            // Bring up the friends sent confirmation
            $("#friends_sent").fadeIn("slow");
            //$("#optin").attr('false', true);

            // Fade out the confirmation
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#friends_sent").fadeOut("slow")
            },10000);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I'm not really sure why Firefox is submitting the page with Refresh but IE isn't, I've looked over and over the code and can't find the error. Firebug is only finding errors in the jQuery library itself.

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you include the jquery full js to make debug easier. It looks as if its the meta information inside the class attribute on friend_2_email.

Comment: OK, just included the full jquery js rather than compressed.

Comment: it is the invalid markup. See my comment under my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got various validation issues in your  XHTML 1.0 Transitional markup. IE is being nice by helping you out. FF is more strict and will fail.

The lack of input closing tags is playing havoc with the selectors inside the validation script. On the 1st friend email it is actually trying to get the text of an li element!

See the following [w3c validator check](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jakeisonline.com%2Fstackoverflow%2Fjqueryvalidation%2Fpage%2F%3Ffirst_name%3D%26email%3D%26optin%3Dyes%26friend_1_name%3D%26friend_1_email%3D%26friend_2_name%3D%26friend_2_email%3D%26friend_3_name%3D%26friend_3_email%3D%26x%3D98%26y%3D9&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Fix these first, hopefully it will sort the issue. If not report back and I will look again.

Comment: Thank redsquare.

After cleaning up the HTML, to the point of it passing with no errors, warnings - it was still having a bit of an issue. 

It was resolved by accident, I removed the list below the form (for the share buttons) and suddenly it worked. 

Even putting that list back in, in another div below the form would cause issues. I seriously have no idea why this is.

Comment: how odd, if you put the page back up (which errors) I will take a look when I get home

Comment: Thanks. Page is back up, it's the list below the form, the one above doesn't seem to conflict (they are the same, except the top list has an inline style)

Comment: As it stands you are missing two closing divs before you close the form. The markup is the issue.

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste and hack deleting errors, valid markup again. Still the same issue though. 

Looking at the errors, it seems to be when the jQuery Validate Plugin wants to add in the error messages. When it calls jQuery to replace() jQuery throws back an error: (text || "").replace is not a function